# Jitpack Task 'install' is ambiguous in root project Android Library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jcenter, jitpack

I require your help to be able to upload a project, to give them context, I am adding dependencies to my library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:16.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:16.1.2'

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.14.0"

def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
def arch_version = "2.1.0"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"
implementation 'com.github.UlaiS.ocr-recognition:camera:1.0.20'
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'install' is ambiguous in root project 'project'. Candidates are: 'installDebug', 'installDebugAndroidTest'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: locally already try this and compile without problems 'gradlew install'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove `project (': opencv') from settings.gradle. ProjectDir = new File ('/ opencv')`. This is for the purpose of using opencv from the library since I had forgotten to mention it